# Does positive feedback during a tenure track campus interview mean an offer?

Tags: tenure-track, interview, feedback

I had my first on-campus interview 10 days ago at an R1 university, which is not an ivy but a dream job in my field. I was supposed to give a colloquium and present a research talk about my future research and mentoring plans. Not only did every one-on-one interview go well, even after the research talk (that many had told me is the most important factor in decision making) many faculties told me the talk was amazing and they were very impressed with it. Also, I received a lot of positive feedback after the thank-you emails.

Does this mean anything? I don't know what to expect. I know many people say they thought the interview went so well for them, but they didn't end up getting an offer. But I have never heard someone talking about these many positive feedbacks (some in writing). Since I'm extremely stressed and the waiting period is too tough, I appreciate if someone could tell me about their experience, positive or negative...

P.S.: I know 2 out of 3 other candidates in person and they haven't heard either. I also know the last interview was last week.

Comment: The comments of other candidates are not reliable sources of information, especially if they are short-sighted.

Comment: Your underlying assumption here is that from your interactions during and after the interviews and talks, you can get useful information about the outcome of the hiring process. By and large, that assumption is largely false. You generally don't know what's going on behind the scenes and how the other candidates performed. Ultimately, you need to be very patient with hiring processes - it's best to completely forget about particular applications as much as possible after the talks + interviews, focus on your other applications and anything that helps your further build up your track record.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of positive feedback is not to tell you they want to hire you.  There are two goals in mind:

- The positive feedback will encourage you to accept the job if it is offered to you.
- The positive feedback establishes a good working relationship if you end up getting the job, which might happen in the distant future.

They can also just be polite.

If the search has been run well, all the finalists are qualified for the job.  There is uncertainty that they will accept an offer.  The primary motivation of the department is to ensure that the position is filled.  They do not want to be left understaffed.  They do not want to do the search again.

Nothing you hear between your interview and your offer/rejection is a reliable indicator of what happened during the search.

Answer (score 3):

Only an offer is an offer. If there are several top rated candidates all of them may be getting positive feedback. You made a good impression. You'll have to be satisfied with that until something official is done. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You thought your interview and talk went well, you got good feedback, and the email indicates you're probably still in the running. That's encouraging but not a guarantee. You'll find out whether you got the appointment when they decide to tell you. That's all that can be known for now.

In short, it means you likely have a good chance.  But don't count your chickens before they hatch.

Comment: Thanks @Nicole for the answer. Do you say this based on the positive feedback or the email? So it's not so common to be positive to everyone, right?

Comment: @tenuretrackjobseeker moved my response into my answer.